# Need to populate an array with query results and json_encode those results (within codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

My query works fine and returns over 1000 rows. However when ran through the following foreach loop, only the first row of records is returned in JSON encode and is recognised as a string and not an array.

Here is the loop:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
    $row['Client_Desc'];
    $row['Parent_Entity_Name'];
    $row['Entity_Name'];
    $row['trackbacknumber'];
    $row['external_reference'];
    $row['effective_start_date_time'];
    $row['effective_end_date_time']."<br />";
}
var_dump(json_encode($row, TRUE));
```

And the result which is returned is as follows:....

```
string '{"Client_Desc":"FGA-Italy","Parent_Entity_Name":"Fiat Italy","Entity_Name":"Fiat Italy     Dealer","trackbacknumber":"390236000471","external_reference":"0","effective_start_date_time":"04\/03    \/2013 10:13:57","effective_end_date_time":"01\/01\/3000 00:00:00"}' (length=255)
```

Am I using result_array correctly?

Thanks for your time. All help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing nothing inside the loop it will take last row in the for each loop.
If you want all the rows you need to pass it to a array `$data[] = $row;`

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
$data[] = $row;
}
var_dump(json_encode($data, TRUE));
```

Regarding the string you are getting after the json_encode, it is because its return type is a string.
[PHP Manual- json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Hi mate. Thanks for replying. I have entered the following:...
    
    `foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
    $data['Client_Desc'] = $row;
    $data['Parent_Entity_Name'] = $row;
    $data['Entity_Name'] = $row;
    $data['trackbacknumber'] = $row;
    $data['external_reference'] = $row;
    $data['effective_start_date_time'] = $row;
    $data['effective_end_date_time'] = $row;
    }
    var_dump(json_encode($data, TRUE));`

It has now returned rows nested in each other. Its too long to paste entire string but here's the beginning... `'{"Client_Desc":{"Client_Desc":...`

Comment: Have you got any other suggestions subas_poudel?

I seems i am getting closer to a clean return of results.

Comment: try this 

$data[]['Client_Desc'] = $row['Client_Desc'];
$data[]['Parent_Entity_Name'] = $row['Parent_Entity_Name'];

Comment: I can't see that working buddy. Where's the logic in what you have typed? Thanks.

Comment: i am not understanding you properly here, are you saying you are not getting a array after json_encode? it returns a string value.

Comment: no. i have over 1000 records which this query returns, however originally i was only returning a single row/record in JSON. So somewhere in the foreach loop it was either overwriting other records or not looping through the entirety of the query results.

Comment: you are doing nothing inside the loop. Please refer my answer.

Comment: I'm still quite new to codeigniter and loops so still a bit rookie during troubleshooting. I have attempted changes based on your latest suggestions and now receive no results. Sorry. But its still knackered!

Comment: what are your changes based on my suggestions. can you share it?

Comment: well you're latest suggestion outputs an empty screen so i have resorted back to two different versions as follows:

A) `foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['Client_Desc'];
   echo $row['Parent_Entity_Name'];
   echo $row['Entity_Name'];
   echo $row['trackbacknumber'];
   echo $row['external_reference'];
   echo $row['effective_start_date_time'];
   echo $row['effective_end_date_time']."<br />";
}`

This does return all records so understanding how to simply JSON_encode this could solve my issue!!! :)

Comment: And my second version returns only the first row from the query but in full JSON encode.

`foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   $row['Client_Desc'];
   $row['Parent_Entity_Name'];
   $row['Entity_Name'];
   $row['trackbacknumber'];
   $row['external_reference'];
   $row['effective_start_date_time'];
   $row['effective_end_date_time']."<br />";
}
var_dump(json_encode($row, TRUE));`

Comment: second version doesnot do anything inside foreach loop. first version is ok.
I am not sure what and how you are using my answer. good luck

Comment: Granted the first version is returning a valid number of results however i still need to json encode the entire array.

Comment: the answer i provided you works perfectly, i tested it. I am assuming you include the code in the model and pass it to view via controller. Can you tell me how you are using it further.

Comment: i am completely stuck. I am running it like i have just showed you in the previous pastes of code. Could you please demonstrate how you have done it so that it works.

Comment: I tried your suggestion as follows and only returns a single row...like i said.

`foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
 $data['Client_Desc'] = $row;
 $data['Parent_Entity_Name'] = $row;
 $data['Entity_Name'] = $row;
 $data['trackbacknumber'] = $row;
 $data['external_reference'] = $row;
 $data['effective_start_date_time'] = $row;
 $data['effective_end_date_time'] = $row;
}

var_dump(json_encode($row, TRUE));`

Could you please just demonstrate how you tested it.

Comment: dont use $data['Client_Desc'] = $row; why do you want it that way?
just use
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) { 
data[]=$row;
} and do var_dump

Comment: how am i supposed to do it then>?

Comment: replace the code you have pasted in your question with the code in answer without modification.

Comment: Yes! thank you, i was barking up the wrong tree with that. Sorry.

I have a single string which has every row from the query in it. How would i go about separating them into their individual rows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i am not getting you here. if you want just an array of rows you do not need to json_encode it. just use $data. var_dump($data).
if you still want to use json encode you can use json_decode(json_encode($row, TRUE))
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60839/discussion-on-answer-by-subas-poudel-need-to-populate-an-array-with-query-result).